# Angular 4: Zone file is loaded already

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal. It appears for while then disappear with below error details in the browser console. Any help is appriciated.

```
Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded.
    at <anonymous>:2577:15
    at <anonymous>:3188:3
    at webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.FUNCTION (<anonymous>:2554:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:2557:2)
    at Object.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js (<anonymous>:5380:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (<anonymous>:55:30)
    at Object.../../../../../src/polyfills.ts (<anonymous>:12:76)
    at __webpack_require__ (<anonymous>:55:30)
    at Object.1 (<anonymous>:5387:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (<anonymous>:55:30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your not loading the module twice. Check this file was not loaded two times:

```
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have included it once but not sure from where it is loading twice.

Comment: If it loaded twice - you can see the source who executed script load in Chrome toolbar in network tab -> Initiator column.

Comment: Seems like polyfills.bundle.js reloading that twice.

Comment: It is second time. Maybe you can remove from first place?

Comment: Application require zone file is error occurs when I try it